# Problem with parameters in url and pagination

Tags: plugin-development, pagination, page-template

I created a custom template page and I show users list in it. I have a pagination for this users list and when I add a user to this list, I show a message at the top. This messaged is created from a parameter in the URL, so when I create a new user, my page URL becomes this:

```
example.com/?message=success
```

And I print a message. 
But the problem is when I click on a pagination link, the URL changes to this and pagination does not work:

```
example.com/?message=successpage/2
```

But it should be:

```
example.com/page/2
```

How can I fix this? 
This is the code I used for pagination:

```
$current_page = max(1, get_query_var('paged'));
esc_url(remove_query_arg( 'message' ));
echo paginate_links(array(
    'base'          =>  get_pagenum_link(1) . '%_%',
    'format'        =>  'page/%#%/',
    'current'       =>  $current_page,
    'total'         =>  intval($total_patients / 10) + 1,
    'prev_next'     =>  true,
    'type'          =>  'list',
));
```

Comment: "I create my pagination with `paginate_links` function" - what is your code? Add it to your question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `remove_query_arg()` function. [DOCUMENTATION](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/remove_query_arg/) and [EXAMPLES](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/remove_query_arg/#user-contributed-notes)

```
remove_query_arg( 'message' ) ;
```

in pagination code like this.

```
$current_page = max(1, get_query_var('paged'));
echo paginate_links(array(
    'base'          =>  remove_query_arg( 'message',get_pagenum_link(1) ) . '%_%',
    'format'        =>  'page/%#%/',
    'current'       =>  $current_page,
    'total'         =>  intval($total_patients / 10) + 1,
    'prev_next'     =>  true,
    'type'          =>  'list',
));
```

Comment: I added the code before pagination, but still the pagination links have the message parameter.

Comment: @Amirition I have updated my answer.